# Get authenticated user in view decorator

Tags: python, django, decorator

I am trying to capture the audit trail of all the `GET` requests using a decorator but I have a problem capturing the authenticated user. I would like to get my authenticated user from the header which contains a JWT token that contains the user id.

Suppose I have the following view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @audit_view_action()
    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_users(self.request.user)
```

and the following decorator:

```
def audit_view_action():
    def decorator_func(func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            retval = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return retval
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator_func
```

Is there a way to get the active user? I have tried getting it from the `request`  `request.context['request']` but the `request` is only a `UserViewSet` object and doesn't have a `context` attribute.

Comment: Since `request` is an `UserViewSet` object, did you tried `request.request.user`?

Comment: no and that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! That solved my problem.

Comment: The point being, of course, that the first argument is not actually `request` at all, but `self`.